# Calling a contract method ends in error

Tags: web3js, ether

I'm trying to call a contract method from the web3 interface in node.js (via testrpc) which should return a Boolean value.

```
contract_instance.my_method()
```

This outputs an error:

> /node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:61
>
> throw errors.InvalidResponse(result);
>
> Error: AssertionError: The field to must have byte length of 20

I also tried

```
contract_instance.my_method.call(function(error, result) {  
  console.log(result);
});
```

That outputs the same error. Whenever I comment out the result log the error disappears. In the testrpc logs the call is registered.

Comment: what is your function's code?

Comment: `function my_method() constant returns (bool) {
    return state;
  }`

which returns

`bool private state`

Answer (score 1):

Got the problem.

Instead of

`var contract_instance = my_contract.at(["0xf6b0fc7bbb00fa5f47de4cd5d92157365276a0d3"]);`

I had to use

`var contract_instance = my_contract.at("0xf6b0fc7bbb00fa5f47de4cd5d92157365276a0d3");`

Answer (score 0):

your code doesn't seem to be the source of your error, its seems to be a testrpc problem i advise you to open an issue on their [github](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc).

I've deployed a simple contract on [Ropsten](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x9da874fc3562ed2adfac923a59948674939e5e8f) [testnet](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x55c77e9c98187ff9123f2becafc66efd9a1218bf)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;


        contract test{

            bool private state;
            function my_method() constant returns (bool) { return state; }

        }
```

calling the my_method using Web3js(+Metamask) it works perfectly :

```
contract.my_method(function(error, result){
     if(!error)
         console.log("result:"+result)
     else
         console.error("error:"+error);
 });
```

the whole code test is available [here](https://gist.github.com/bellaj/185ac7557ef9825a6e72034996b671ea)